# Cleaner way to write code snippet

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm new to java and I was wondering if there was an easier way to write

```
if(a == 10 || b == 10){
    //stuff
}
```

In my mind I tried something like this:

```
if(a||b == 10){
    //stuff
}
```

because IMO that makes a lot of intuitive sense, but it's not a thing.

Comment: Nope, you can't make it shorter.

Comment: You can remove the braces if the statement under `if` is one line

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I strongly recommend not doing that, even though it would be valid code.

Comment: In Java9 you can write `if (Set.of(a,b).contains(10))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're only comparing a few values then you might as well proceed with the current approach as there is nothing in place to make it shorter. However, if you're repeating your self many times, then you can create a helper function to do the work for you.

i.e

```
static boolean anyMatch(int comparisonValue, int... elements){
        return Arrays.stream(elements)
                     .anyMatch(e -> e == comparisonValue);
}
```

then call it like so:

```
if(anyMatch(10, a, b)){ ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not going to work like that. You're checking the value of two variables against a value, which ends up being two checks, `if(a == 10 || b == 10)`.

However, you can modify this check to this code:

```
if(Arrays.asList(a,b).contains(10))
```

It results in the same behavior, but this is neither shorter nor easier to read.

Comment: Are you sure `Arrays.asList()` has a good performance than `||`?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Of course not. It's horrible. It creates a ``List`` and then ``contains`` checks each element.

Comment: Why this answer has no upvotes? No doubt there are performance issues with both the answers when compared to `logicalOR` but this has a shorter syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah turns out there isn't a way to make it shorter.

Answer (score 0):

No, we can't do it because in case of java, there is no option for comparison of variables like that.
Even you couldn't write like this

```
if(a||b){ //staff }
```

but if you would write then you will get this error message

> error: bad operand types for binary operator '||'

Answer (score 0):

Not shorter, but more "intuitively" readable:

```
boolean condA = (a == 10);
boolean condB = (b == 10);

if(condA || condA){
    //stuff
}
```

always keep in mind, the goal isn't to write *shortest* possible code, but *best maintainable* code.